# How to port forward from Eclipse Che instance to local machine?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, eclipse-che

## Background

So after about a year of  having a GoDaddy cloud service, and super disappointed with it from the get-go. Once they announced that they would be discontinuing Cloud Server services, it was like a sign from the heavens.

I then created a Google Cloud account. One of the biggest reasons I got a Cloud Server to begin with was to have an eclipse Che instance, an IDE  wherever you are!  I love it, but despite the temporary partnership between Bitnami and GoDaddy, launching a Eclipse instance with them with such a mind-numbing task since their internal Factory build still required a ton of Docker configurations...

And though I can appreciate the fact that I did learn the ins-and-outs of configuring Dockers Network settings,  which is not something to wince at... As soon as I got my Google Cloud account it was simply a 1 2 3 and go!

## Question

Whilst I'm running an Eclipse chat instance, what is the proper way to port-forward a given work space to my local machine?  The scenario is simple...

I created a Python stack of which I am using Django but when I run server,  of course default being the local IP to the project,  I have yet to find the easy and more than likely existing standard way to run the  Django server and have the eclipse Che create the URL to the project.  I'm ninety-nine percent sure that I'm going about this the wrong way given the fact that even some of the demo stack projects with Node or Python are plug-and-play.

PS: I am able to ssh into the workspace no issue, I'm just confused on how to port forward from remote to local as I've only really done it the other way around.. ssh -R ... or -L?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is SSH Tunnel, which is `-L`. If you need to send a port from local to server that is called a Reverse SSH Tunnel, which is `-R`.

so simple command

```
ssh -L <localport>:127.0.0.1:<remoteport> <user>@<server>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some extension to the other answer mentioning ssh tunneling...

If you run a docker-dev on a server (e.g. 192.168.1.123) not being your local machine in eclipse-che that provides some web service you want to access, then find out the IP address of the docker-dev, e.g. by opening a terminal in your eclipse che workspace and executing `ip addr`. There you will see some 172.17.x.x that is accessible only from the server. Assume the service in docker-dev is listening on port 12345, then you need the following ssh port forwarding from your local machine to access it:

```
ssh -L 8888:172.17.0.2:12345 192.168.1.123
```

While the ssh connection is open, you can access the web service with you browser by accessing http://127.0.0.1:8888/